# Azure : HOWTO/BEST-Practice : Publish WebApp with Webjob using blobs Q's to multiple destinations?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-storage, publish

I have a webapp that I publish from VS. I have 3 publishing profiles (Test, Demo and Production). Each targets a different server on Azure, with it's own SQl behind it. I added a webjob using Queue's and Blob-storage. Again for test, demo and production I create 3 different storage accounts.

On publishing time to set different connection strings for the SQL-connection is straightforward. Just change the in the publishing wizard.

But what about the connection string for the storage account ? How to have them changed on publishing time to the correct environment ?

Comment: If you down-vote a question. Be so fair to add a comment why you did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question : set key in your App webconfig with dummy values

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="BLOBAzure1" value="Check Azure" />
</appSettings>
```

Get connection string for blob at runtime with something like this:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("BLOBAzure1"));
```

Inside Azure Panel go to your Web app properties and set REAL keys inside APP SETTING.
Redeploy projects and all work fine.

Read this article if you have any doubts [Windows Azure Web Sites: How Application Strings and Connection Strings Work](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/)